# Ubuntu 20.04.2 Live ISO autoinstall

Tags: system-installation, subiquity

I am trying to do an autoinstall using the live server iso (20.04.2 server LTS) and after getting through the boot loader it just hangs at the welcome screen and wants me to interactively choose my language.  I have a really simple user-data file:

```
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
```

I intend to add more later, but I was just trying to get it to do something to get past that initial screen.   When I look at /var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt it shows my version of the file, but it seems as though the autoinstall is not occurring and I don't know why.

I would prefer to use the new autoinstall method, but if I can't find a solution to make this completely automated I will need to look into using the legacy installer.

Any insight on where to look for clues on making this thing execute properly is very appreciated.

Comment: The Ubuntu Server Guide should be your first stop for most Ubuntu Server questions: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

Comment: I agree and I have looked through that completely

Comment: One thing to note in the doc it says there will be a file called /var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data, but that file does not exist on my system.  However my user-data file exists at /var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt.   Not sure if that helps diagnose this issue.

Comment: Are you saying that the [Quickstart example](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart) does not work for you?

Comment: Clues can be found in the debug and info logs in `/var/log/installer`.  Your problem could be any number of things, but one thing that jumps out at me is your `user-data` file is missing `#cloud-config` at the top. This line is *not* optional.

Comment: That seems to have worked. The documentation is a bit unclear on that being a required element or I just missed it.  Thank you!